# Derivative of F-norm with Kronecker product

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule, kronecker-product

For the function:

$f=\frac{\alpha}{2}\|A(I_{d}\otimes X)B\|_{F}^{2}+\frac{\beta}{2}\|X-Z\|_{F}^{2},$

where $X,Z\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, A\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times dm},B\in\mathbb{R}^{dn\times\ell}$. What is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $X$? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}$To
avoid confusion with derivatives and differentials change the variable $d\to p$.

Let's also define
the variables
$$\eqalign{
Y &= I_p\otimes X &\in\R{pm\times pn} \\
W &= A^TAYBB^T &\in\R{pm\times pn} \\
\e_k &= \{k^{th}\,{\rm column\,of}\,I_p\} &\in\R{p\times{\tt1}} \\
M_k &= \e_k\otimes I_m &\in\R{pm\times m} \\
N_k &= \e_k\otimes I_n &\in\R{pn\times n} \\
S &= \sum_{k=1}^p M_k^TWN_k &\in\R{m\times n} \\
}$$
and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
S:X &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n S_{ij} X_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}\left(SX^T\right) \\
X:X &= \big\|X\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Write the function using the above notation, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \tfrac 12\alpha(AYB):(AYB) +\tfrac 12\beta(X-Z):(X-Z) \\
df &= \alpha(AYB):A\,dY\,B + \beta(X-Z):dX \\
 &= \alpha W:dY + \beta(X-Z):dX \\
 &= \alpha S:dX + \beta(X-Z):dX \\
\grad{f}{X} &= \alpha S + \beta X -\beta Z \\\\
}$$

---

Let's expand the key identity that was used above
$$\eqalign{
S:dX
 &= \sum_{k=1}^p M_k^TWN_k:dX  \\
 &= W:\sum_{k=1}^p M_k\,dX\,N_k^T \\
 &= W:\sum_{k=1}^p (\e_k\otimes I_m)\,(I_{\tt1}\otimes dX)\,(\e_k^T\otimes I_n) \\
 &= W:\sum_{k=1}^p (\e_k\e_k^T)\otimes(I_m\,dX\,I_n) \\
 &= W:(I_p\otimes dX) \\
 &= W:dY \\
}$$